# Convergence of sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^{2p}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to say that this series converges for $p>0.5$  I know that I can use this inequality to compare

$$\frac{1}{n^{2p}}<\frac{\ln n}{n^{2p}}<\frac{n}{n^{2p}}=\frac{1}{n^{2p-1}}$$

where $n\ge 1$ and certainly summing the middle terms, it will diverge if $p\le 0.5$  But the right side, we have convergence if $2p-1>1$ or when $p>1$.  So what happens in $(0.5,1)$?  What am I not doing?

Comment: Do you know the integral test?

Comment: Or you could bound $\ln n$ by $n^c$ for any small $c>0$ you want, instead of $n$.

Comment: Simply be more careful with your inequality. $\ln n < n$ is too rough. But $$\ln n < n^\varepsilon$$ works for all $\varepsilon >0$.

Comment: @Crostul ...for $n$ sufficiently large. Don't forget that part. :)

Comment: I figured that $n$ was too large a comparison, but it made the p-series test easy.  How can you show $\ln n<n^{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @Frpzzd, how would the integral test work here?  It could be shown that the function $\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{2p}}$ is continous, decreasing, and positive, but how would the integral evaluate?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven It can at least be used for the case of $p=0.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

1. If $p\in(1,\infty)$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}<\infty$.
2. If $p\in[0,1],$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}=\infty$.

Proof: 1. Let $p\in(1,\infty)$. Let $a=\frac{p-1}{2}>0$. Note that
when $n$ is sufficiently large, $\ln n<n^{a}$. (For, by L'Hospital
rule, $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{ax^{a-1}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}ax^{a}=+\infty$.)
Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\ln n<n^{a}$ whenever $n\geq N$.
Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}$.
Note that $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}\leq\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p-a}}<\infty$
because $p-a=\frac{p+1}{2}>1$ (Power Test). It follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}<\infty$.

2. Let $p\in[0,1]$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{p}}\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=\infty$
   by Integral Test.

Comment: Integral test?  Isn't the integral test involve integrals?

Comment: For the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}$, it is divergent because $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x} dx =\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} (\ln a)^2/2 =+\infty$

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if $p\in (0.5,1)$ you can write $p=c+d, c>0.5, d>0$, $\sum {1\over {n^{2c}}}$ converges ${ln(n)\over{n^{2p}}}\over{1\over {n^{2c}}}$=${{ln(n)}\over {n^{2d}}}$ which converges towards $0$ so the comparison test implies that the serie converges.

Comment: So by limit comparison...okay.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \frac{\frac{\ln n}{n^{2p}}}{\frac 1 {n^a}}=\frac{\ln n}{n^{2p-a}}\to0 \implies 2p-a>0\implies a<2p$$

moreover the given series converges by limit comparison test if and only if $a>1$ that is for $2p>1 \implies p>\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents.

We will show the convergence using Cauchy condensation test, namely:

> **Lemma:** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive monotone decreasing sequence. Then we have that
>   \begin{align}
> \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n <\infty \ \ \ \text{ if and only if } \ \ \ \sum^\infty_{k=1}2^ka_{2^k}<\infty.
> \end{align}

Using this fact, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}2^ka_{2^k} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}2^k \frac{k\log 2}{2^{2pk}} = (\log 2)\sum^\infty_{k=1} k\left(\frac{1}{2^{2p-1}}\right)^k
\end{align}
which is summable provided
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2^{2p-1}}<1 \ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ 0<(2p-1)\log 2  \ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2}<p.
\end{align}
Hence we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{\log n}{n^{2p}}<\infty \ \ \ \text{ if and only if }  \ \ \ \frac{1}{2}<p.
\end{align}

Comment: Condensation test is a big cannon, we don’t need to use that here.